# Unable to make a dropdown list searchable

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a dropdown list in my view page but it is not a searchable dropdown, this is how I populate dropdown values

```
 public ActionResult SpecialOrderSummary(int? id)
        {
            ItemViewModel model = (ItemViewModel)TempData["model"];
            TempData.Keep("model");
           
            var part = (from i in db.Parts.Where(x => x.deleted == false)
                        select new
                        {
                            partID = i.ID,
                            partName = i.PartID  + i.Name
                        }).OrderBy(x => x.partName).ToList();
                   
            ViewBag.PartID = new SelectList(part, "partID", "partName");
                   
            return View(model);
        }
```

And here is how I set it up in my view

```
<div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.DropDownList("PartID", null, "-- Select --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control chosen-select Part-select" })
</div>
```

I have set it up the same way in other parts of my system and it properly makes the dropdown searchable, but it is not working for this scenario. The dropdown also looks different than it normally does as usually it looks like this

[image: correct way]

But currently my dropdown is looking like this

[image: not searchable]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.Net doesn't support searchable dropdowns by default. You can use select2 dropdown which is a wrapper around normal dropdown.

Try this:

**Step 1:** Import the necessary css and script:

```
 <!-- Bootstrap css-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <!-- Select2 css-->
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**Step 2:** Your Actual Dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownList("PartID", null, "-- Select --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control chosen-select Part-select" })
```

**Step 3:** Bind the searchable select2 dropdown on page load using jquery

```
 <!-- JQuery script-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Select2 script-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.chosen-select').select2({     // .chosen-select is class name(from your dropdown)
            placeholder: "Select"
        });
  });
```

Sample output:

[image]

NOTES:

- The order of scripts is VERY important. Mention their order as I have mentioned here.
- Best practice is to mention the style links above(within head tag) and scripts below(within your body tag)
- If you get stuck here is the link: [Codepen-Searchable Dropdown demo](https://codepen.io/riyos94/pen/VyBdBz/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=cfc704f098bd7f2dbb659efe50034ccea5f28746-1596261884-0-Adq_ZoJ1OCRRhWtWbHuVZ-InusCrTDJsN6lVGH_Y_ixPYjwYmUFNZ3MzXc6vMORF3WPUmxqwqgJiMDRet-vI5XOLsjSdh9kDPThod7oIh-gVVGSJfnuso845SRX5mKpCuKpl_G9S2lrc4khkPsDSLZ16y9AwsDRO5e3SfAjth3ldu24dXwTiY5usKP84cJsQVl9uNPiBIYC3hH1PLyG8XM3KNF-ataC7VFqAfb6pY9wwtYobQzKXBVxJEQy8JGYvkcpiPSHmxhSkXNSwU0FNj422Xjz6CGEHjNSiuC2kyUdAfVmBdEwmOoDc4Kk1JwHrUQqfvNBFPr88kwottbjEB18wqVjNp837MMQ5nlOXQeiV)

Comment: Thanks! I'm just confused by why my dropdown is searchable in other parts of my program though? They are setup the same way and as you can see they also look different as well

Comment: And it is not recognizing select2, and I made sure that the order of scripts was correct

Comment: nevermind I was able to get it to work. The feature is very finnicky