# Fieldset bugged after add importing css and script

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, webforms

So I was just trying to do a dropdown list searchable that i found in here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63198421/unable-to-make-a-dropdown-list-searchable)

but when I checked my fieldset is unformattedAnd for example the border color is gone and the font size changed too and I dont know why all of this changed just by importing some css and scripts.
If you could help me to solve this out I would be very gratefull.

code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DSV.aspx.cs" Inherits="Gestão_de_embarques.DSV" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MenuBar.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Select2 CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div class="principal">
            <div class="txtbox">
                <div class="rz-fieldset-content">
                    <asp:Button ID="NewBooking" runat="server" Text="New booking" OnClick="NewBooking_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="EditBooking" runat="server" Text="Edit booking" OnClick="EditBooking_Click" />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBL" Style="text-align: center; display: block; color: red;" ErrorMessage="Spaces are not allowed!" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="[^\s]+" />
                    <asp:Label ID="Erro" runat="server" Style="text-align: center; display: block; color: red;" Text="Erro! Preencha todos os campos!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="BookingSent" runat="server" Style="text-align: center; display: block; color: black;" Text="BL enviado com sucesso!" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
                    <fieldset id="Fieldset" runat="server">
                        <legend>Encomendas</legend>
                        <table>
                            <tr id="TrSearch" runat="server">
                                <td>
                                    <div class="input-container">
                                        <input type="text" id="Text1" runat="server" class="input-field" style="color: black;" placeholder="Pesquisar.." />
                                        <button id="Button1" class="wrapper" onserverclick="btnsearch_Click" runat="server"><i class="fas fa-search" style="color: #8b9095;"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Style="display: block; color: black; font-size: 15px;" Text="Nº BL"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBL" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="TrBL" runat="server">
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Style="display: block; color: black; font-size: 15px;" Text="Selecione o BL"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListBL" CssClass="txt" Style="padding-right: 10px; color: grey;" runat="server">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="- -" />
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="TrContentor" runat="server">
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Nº Contentor"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Ño_contentor" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="TrOrigem" runat="server">
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Origem"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Pais" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Porto" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="TrTipologia" runat="server">
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Tipologia"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" CssClass="txt" Style="padding-right: 10px; color: grey;" runat="server">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text='- -' />
                                        <asp:ListItem Text='20"' />
                                        <asp:ListItem Text='40"' />
                                        <asp:ListItem Text='40"HC' />
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </fieldset>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="ButtonSave_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Back" OnClick="ButtonBack_Click" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <%--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Select2 -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#DropDownListBL").select2({
                /*placeholder: "Select a programming language",*/
                allowClear: true
            });
        </script>--%>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: The css from select2 must have some conflicting styles. Try moving the select2 css include above your other css and see if that changes anything. Maybe use inspect element to check if styles from select2 are being applied. Also, are you saying that the searchable dropdown isn't working? Or just the css display is broken?

Comment: only the css, i removed and its already fine